# Slow slew rate causes signal inversion, missed pulses

Tags: slew-rate

I’m currently revising a legacy design using an old Lattice MACH 5  PLD. One of the (TTL) inputs to the PLD has a slow slew rate on the rising edge, spending some 25ns between 0.8V and 2.0V, and the 10-90% rise time takes much longer.

It has been my understanding that a slow edge like this can cause oscillation, double-clocking, and heightened power consumption in the input buffer, but I was using the signal strictly as an input to an 8 MHz state machine, so I figured there would be no issue.

Boy, was I wrong! When I tested the system, my state machine behaved erratically. I changed the PLD to buffer and output the signal in question, revealing what I believe to be the cause of the issue:

[image: slow slew rate signs, buffered and unbuffered]

The bottom trace shows the signal as input to the PLD, and the top trace shows the signal as buffered and output. Look at those missing pulses and inversion! Wow! I never knew such a thing was possible, particularly the inversion. I have reproduced this with multiple PLDs, and the effect does not occur when buffering a faster signal. Has anyone seen this effect before? I have seen oscillation and double-clocking, but nothing like this.

Edit: Brian suggested that it was a synchronization problem, but unfortunately it’s not. Below is an additional scope trace showing the 8 MHz clock at the bottom, the slow signal above, and then the outputs of a 3-long shift register with the slow signal as an input.

[image: registered]

Comment: The signals are all in the same clock domain. The slow signal is a registered output + combinational delay from a chip fed by the 8 MHz clock. The slow signal changes only after the 8 MHz clock's rising edge, and always reaches 2.0V before the next rising edge of the 8 MHz clock. So there are no setup/hold violations.

Comment: It must be an edge sensitive input, so you need a Schmitt trigger to negate the effects of trace or cable inductance.  The ringing noise increases with TTL output voltage above 1.5V as the impedance rises.

Comment: Can you show the actual logic you have implemented? The output looks too regular to just be as you suspect.

Comment: You would think it’s edge sensitive, but the signal is used strictly as an input, not a clock or latch enable, nor are there any combinational feedback loops in the design. 

The first picture has verilog of the form Y=A, asynchronous. 

The second picture is Y[2:0]<={Y[1:0], A}, registered at the rising edge of the 8MHz clock. The high-order bits of the shift register work correctly, but despite plenty of setup and hold time for the A input, the Y[0] output reflects the same kind of glitch as in the first picture.

Comment: This MACH 5 device is not a “true” CMOS PLD. It’s sense amplifier-based like a PAL. I have all the “turbo bits” on (and this 256 macrocell device consumes 0.2A at dc!) and also turned off all of the “logic optimization” features of the Synplify compiler. 

I think there is some kind of power-down feature somewhere that’s responsible for this issue, sort of like “zero-power” GALs which automatically power down their sense amplifiers in the absence of input transitions. Although something is consuming 0.2A at DC, it’s conceivable that part of the device powers down in this way.